# Potential First Answer Review Bug

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

So, while reviewing today, I ran across what appeared to be a bug in the review queue.  Prior to this post, I had reviewed several others without issue and almost skipped this one but after looking at it a bit closer, it was very strange.

The review queue told me the question had 0 views, was answered today, and was from a new (although not listed) user (none of which were true upon further investigation).

Here are the screen shots of the post as it existed in the queue:
[image]
...
[image]

But, when visiting the direct link next to the review, I see this:

[image]
...
[image]

I still have the review queue open, in case there are any questions.

Here is a direct link to the question / answer: [How to handle `Reader` monad and `Try`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949608/how-to-handle-reader-monad-and-try/25950063#25950063)

Any idea what caused this?

Comment: You are looking at a review audit. The post has been obscured on purpose.

Comment: I see.  Should I remove this question, given it is a duplicate?

Comment: You can't anymore, not with an upvoted answer.

Comment: Good job for paying attention ;)

Comment: Good for paying attention maybe, not do good for checking meta for this question before posting.. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an audit.  It's there to make sure you're paying attention.  If you don't take the proper review action then the system would know that you didn't review it properly.